# By using while/for loop, how to subtract ONLY the uppercase of a line input by users?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, char, uppercase

Here is my code, i used `is.upperCase` to check but it doesn't seem to work. And i have trouble concatenating all the uppercases together. Any suggestion and help would be appreciated!

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class UpperCase  {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); 
        System.out.print("Please input a random line that contain uppercase letters in any positions: ");
        String str = in.next();

        int i = 0;

        while (i < str.length() - 1) {
            if(Character.isUpperCase(i)) { 
                char upperLetter = str.charAt(i);
            }    

            Object outputLetter = str.charAt(0) + str.charAt(i++);
            char upperLetter = str.charAt(i++);
        }

        System.out.println("The uppercase letters are:" );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess below would solve your problem.

```
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please input a random line that contain uppercase letters in any positions: ");
        String str = in.nextLine();
        char[] cr = str.toCharArray();
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        for(int i=0;i<cr.length;i++){
            if(Character.isUpperCase(cr[i])){
                stringBuffer.append(cr[i]);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The uppercase letters are:" + stringBuffer);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, your idea is correct, but the way you did implement has some mistakes
1. isUperCase of i -> Wrong
2. outputLetter should be declare outside the loop to advoid re-init data
3. outputLetter should be something like outputLetter += anUpperCase
4. finally, refer this bellow code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please input a random line that contain uppercase letters in any positions: ");
        String str = in.next();
        in.close();
        int i = 0;
        String result = "";
        while (i < str.length() - 1) {

            char aChar = str.charAt(i);

            if (Character.isUpperCase(aChar)) {
                result += aChar;
            }
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println("The uppercase letters are: " + result);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!! I will try run both of the codes. Thanks again.